# How to prevent rascal_builder from running on every save in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, rascal

I've been working on a Rascal project in Eclipse 2018. The project is roughly 500 LOC. My problem is that saving a file within the project takes about 20 to 40 seconds. This is due to rascal_builder running after every save.

Since I am accustomed to saving many times during editing, this is starting to reduce my productivity. Is there a way to stop rascal_builder from being invoked every save and have it run only when actual execution of the program is requested? I am not interested in conserving the syntactic annotations for e.g. wrong declarations, missing quotes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in the configuration part of eclipse, `CMD+,` on Mac, go to the Rascal section and disable the experimental compiler flag.