# "The type of pattern could not be computed" when iterating over aliased rel[loc,str,int,int]

Tags: rascal

I have a `rel[loc, str, int, int]` which I aliased as `ECCModel`

Iterating over it in a function results in an error "Type of pattern could not be computed" when elements of the pattern are called `location`. When named anything other than `location`, the errors disappear. Is "location" a reserved word in Rascal? Regardless of the errors, it will compile and run just fine.

The error can be produced with the following method

```
alias ECCModel = rel[loc, str, int, int]
map[str,int] Foo(ECCModel bar)
{
    return (y : z | <location, y, z, _> <- bar);
}
```

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54379794/how-to-prevent-rascal-builder-from-running-on-every-save-in-eclipse-ide

Answer (score 1):

This is not expected behavior and `location` is not a reserved word, but `loc` is.
I think this is a glitch of the current compiler.
For your clarification: we currently have three implementations of Rascal:

- The Rascal interpreter.
- The current (also already sometimes called "old") compiler.
- The new compiler we are working on that is not yet released.

Your example runs fine with the interpreter and new compiler. So the problem you are reporting will disappear over time.